# Como obtengo el valor de los ion-inputs generados dinamicamente en ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, ionic4

Tengo el siguiente caso, en donde itero un array para generar `ion-input`s de acuerdo a los datos del array 
**itemsSueldosSeleccionados** :

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let itemSelecionado of itemsSueldosSeleccionados">
          <ion-label>{{itemSelecionado.itemIngresoGasto}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input (ionChange)="ionChangeValorSueldo($event)" value={{itemSelecionado.montoSueldo}} placeholder="Ingrese monto"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

El array tiene los objetos con las siguientes propiedades :

```
{
idSueldo: 2
idItemSueldo: 1
idItemIngresoGasto: 110
itemIngresoGasto: "Sueldos"
idEmpleado: 1
nombreEmpleado: "Charles Chaparro"
montoSueldo: 1000000
}
```

Necesito obtener los valores que se van cargando en los ion-inputs, pero no se como referenciar o como llegar a cada uno de los elementos html.

Utiliza ionChange para escuchar el cambio de los valores y puedo verlos por consola, pero necesito saber de cual de los input esta cambiando de valor, específicamente obtener el valor la propiedad **idItemIngresoGasto**, ya que es el que ira a la base de datos junto con el monto cargado en el input.

Si podrían ayudarme...desde ya gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues teoricamente y practicamente estos valores cambian dentro del objeto que esta dentro del array a medida que van cambiando sus valores, osea que para acceder por ejemplo a la propiedad value del input:

```
<ion-input (ionChange)="ionChangeValorSueldo($event)" value={{itemSelecionado.montoSueldo}} placeholder="Ingrese monto"></ion-input>
```

Hay dos maneras, la primera es que si necesitas el elemento entero entonces simplemente usa el evento del onchange y luego accede a sus propiedades, que por cierto deberias especificarle que tipo de elemento va a ser con la propiedad type, ya que si no lo especificas, algunas propiedades podrían no existir solo por no especificar de que tipo va a ser el input, entonces en ionChangeValorSueldo tendrias lo siguiente:

```
ionChangeValorSueldo(event){

     //Elemento entero
     console.log(event.target);

     //Propiedades
     console.log(event.target.value);
     console.log(event.target.placeholder);

     //etc

}
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es acceder a un objeto en concreto del arreglo de objetos mediante el evento ionChange, es decir, algo como esto:

```
{
idSueldo: 2
idItemSueldo: 1
idItemIngresoGasto: 110
itemIngresoGasto: "Sueldos"
idEmpleado: 1
nombreEmpleado: "Charles Chaparro"
montoSueldo: 1000000
}
```

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir algo pequeño y corto pero muy importante a tu *ngFor, y es lo siguiente, fijate bien:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let itemSelecionado of itemsSueldosSeleccionados;let i = index">
 </ion-item>
```

Habras visto que se le añade al ***ngFor**:

```
let i = index
```

Que nos permite sacar un indice **numerico** en el cuál se encuentra actualmente el recorrido de ***ngFor**, con esto podemos hacer algo tan interesante como lo siguiente:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let itemSelecionado of itemsSueldosSeleccionados; let i = index">
          <ion-label>{{itemSelecionado.itemIngresoGasto}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input (ionChange)="ionChangeValorSueldo($event, itemsSueldosSeleccionados[i])" value={{itemSelecionado.montoSueldo}} placeholder="Ingrese monto"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

De esta manera ahora podríamos acceder en nuestra función a las propiedades del objeto que cambio mediante el evento ionChange:

```
ionChangeValorSueldo(event, objetoItemSueldos){

     console.log(objetoItemSueldos);

}
```

El resultado en consola sería algo parecido a esto:

```
{
idSueldo: 2
idItemSueldo: 1
idItemIngresoGasto: 110
itemIngresoGasto: "Sueldos"
idEmpleado: 1
nombreEmpleado: "Charles Chaparro"
montoSueldo: 1000000
}
```

Tambien otra cosa que podrias hacer es enviar el indice en vez del objeto en el *ngFor:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let itemSelecionado of itemsSueldosSeleccionados; let i = index">
          <ion-label>{{itemSelecionado.itemIngresoGasto}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input (ionChange)="ionChangeValorSueldo($event, i)" value={{itemSelecionado.montoSueldo}} placeholder="Ingrese monto"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

Y luego en el metodo ionChangeValorSueldo hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
ionChangeValorSueldo(event, index){

     console.log(itemsSueldosSeleccionados[index]);

}
```

Qué es esencialmente el mismo resultado, pero en vez de pasar el objeto completo, pasamos es el indice para luego accederlo mediante nuestro array, el resultado es parecido a este:

```
{
idSueldo: 2
idItemSueldo: 1
idItemIngresoGasto: 110
itemIngresoGasto: "Sueldos"
idEmpleado: 1
nombreEmpleado: "Charles Chaparro"
montoSueldo: 1000000
}
```

Y bueno... ahora de hecho que caigo en cuenta tambien esta una opcion mas sencilla, que es simplemente usar lo que ya tenias en tu *ngFor original:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let itemSelecionado of itemsSueldosSeleccionados">
          <ion-label>{{itemSelecionado.itemIngresoGasto}}</ion-label>
          <ion-input (ionChange)="ionChangeValorSueldo($event, itemSelecionado)" value={{itemSelecionado.montoSueldo}} placeholder="Ingrese monto"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
```

Que tambien funcionaria, ten en cuenta que si se le hizo un cambio, en este caso se le paso un parametro mas a ionChangeValorSueldo(). Pero es esencialmente lo mismo.

Comment: Las tres son validas..,y coincidentemente la tercera solución que planteaste fue la que utilicé para acceder a la información que necesitaba. Te agradezco muchísimo tu tiempo @Riven, excelente la explicación y las opciones que planteaste. Muchas gracias en serio...ahora al recibir la información..intentaré modificar mi observable para enviar la info modifcada a la BD.